# Continue propagation

Tags: javascript, event-propagation

I have some nested elements on my page with a same handler on them which should be called only for an event target without affecting elements higher in DOM tree. To achieve this behavior I used stopPropagation method and it was ok. Then I had to add some handlers for body and other elements outside the nested divs which should be called in any case. Of course stopPropagation isn't an option now but how can I make it work?

Here is a sample:

**html:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="nested1" class="nested">
        <div id="nested2" class="nested">
            <div id="nested3" class="nested">
                <div id="no-handler"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#container {
    display: block;
    width: 398px;
    height: 398px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: solid 1px #888;
}

#nested1 {
    width: 336px;
    height: 336px;
    padding: 30px;
}

#nested2 {
    width: 274px;
    height: 274px;
    padding: 30px;
}

#nested3 {
    width: 212px;
    height: 212px;
    padding: 30px;
}

#no-handler {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: solid 1px #888;
}

.nested {
    border: solid 1px #888;
}

.nested-clicked {
    background-color: red;
}

.outer-clicked {
    background-color: green;
}
```

**js:**

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var nested = document.getElementsByClassName("nested");

function outerHandler(e) {
    this.classList.add("outer-clicked");
}

function nestedHandler(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.classList.add("nested-clicked");
}

container.addEventListener("click", outerHandler, false);
document.body.addEventListener("click", outerHandler, false);
for (var i = 0; i < nested.length; i++) {
    nested[i].addEventListener("click", nestedHandler, false);
}
```

jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/6kgnu7fr/

clicking on `.nested` should add red background color to clicked element and add green color to outer `body` and `#container`

**UPD:**

http://jsfiddle.net/6kgnu7fr/2/

clicking on `#no-event` or any other element inside `.nested` should also call nestedHandler for this `.nested` element.

Comment: you could use the srcElement of the event to actuly validate the element that was clicked `var source = event.target || event.srcElement;`

Comment: This is a good idea. Thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: Tried this solution but have some problems with it. Updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the event's `target` in your `nestedHandler` instead of stopping the propagation. Change the `class` only if the target is `this` so that the effet will only be applied for the `div` on which the event occurred:

```
function nestedHandler(e) {
  if (e.target === this) {
    this.classList.add("nested-clicked");
  }
}
```

**Edit**
Following your edit, this is harder. Way to do it is to find `e.target`'s first ancestor with the "nested" class, then doing the comparison with it instead of `target`:

```
function findAncestorWithClass(dom, targetClass){
  if(!dom){
    return; // (undefined)
  }
  if(dom.classList.contains(targetClass)){
    return dom;
  }
  // terminal recursion
  return findAncestorWithClass(dom.parentNode, targetClass);
}
```

This is naïve shot. You may want to look for a way to make it more efficient, e.g. by avoiding to look for the first ancestor on each `.nested` div.

See the working snipped below.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var nested = document.getElementsByClassName("nested");

function outerHandler(e) {
  this.classList.add("outer-clicked");
}

function findAncestorWithClass(dom, targetClass){
  if(!dom){
    return; // (undefined)
  }
  if(dom.classList.contains(targetClass)){
    return dom;
  }
  // terminal recursion
  return findAncestorWithClass(dom.parentNode, targetClass);
}

function nestedHandler(e) {
  var nestedParent = findAncestorWithClass(e.target, "nested");
  if (this === nestedParent) {
    nestedParent.classList.add("nested-clicked");
  }
}

container.addEventListener("click", outerHandler, false);
document.body.addEventListener("click", outerHandler, false);
for (var i = 0; i < nested.length; i++) {
  nested[i].addEventListener("click", nestedHandler, false);
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: block;
  width: 398px;
  height: 398px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: solid 1px #888;
}
#nested1 {
  width: 336px;
  height: 336px;
  padding: 30px;
}
#nested2 {
  width: 274px;
  height: 274px;
  padding: 30px;
}
#nested3 {
  width: 212px;
  height: 212px;
  padding: 30px;
}
#sub-nested {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.nested {
  border: solid 1px #888;
}
.nested-clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
.outer-clicked {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="nested1" class="nested">
    <div id="nested2" class="nested">
      <div id="nested3" class="nested">
        <div id="sub-nested"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this solution but faced with some problems. Updated question.